# Passing Member Function pointer using variadic template arguments is ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, msvc12

Why is "TArgs" ambiguous in my Example?

The compiler should know the only existing function signature

```
virtual CGame::NetCreatePlayer(CNetPeer* _pPeer, int _ObjectID, const CNetMessage& _ObjectData, bool _bAuthority);
```

and deduce correct `TArgs` in this function:

```
template<typename... TArgs >
void INetInterface<TSubClass>::NetCall(void(TSubClass::*_pFunc)(CNetPeer*, TArgs...), CNetPeer* _pPeer, TArgs... _Params);
```

I want to call it like this:

```
CNetMessage obj;
//...
NetCall(&CGame_Server::NetCreatePlayer, _pClient, 0, obj, true);
```

CGame_Server inherits CGame.

Compiler output:

`4> error C2782: 'void INetInterface<CGame>::NetCall(void (__thiscall CGame::* )(CNetPeer *,TArgs...),CNetPeer *,TArgs...)' 
: template parameter 'TArgs' is ambiguous
4>          NetInterface.h(82) : see declaration of INetInterface<CGame>::NetCall'
4>          could be 'int, const CNetMessage&, bool'
4>          or       'int, CNetMessage, bool'`

It can't be 'int, CNetMessage, bool', right?

Is there a way to get around this problem? 
I tried casting to `const CNetMessage&` but strangely enough that does not help.
And no there are no other member functions with that same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NetCall(&CGame_Server::NetCreatePlayer, _pClient, 0, obj, true);
```

There are two places in this call from which `TArgs` can be deduced:

- From the member function pointer's type, the compiler deduces `TArgs == int, const CNetMessage&, bool`
- From the parameters `0, obj, true`, the compiler deduces `TArgs == int, CNetMessage, bool`

The results conflict. To fix this, use the `identity` trick to put the second `TArgs` into a non-deduced context:

```
template<class T> struct identity { using type = T; };    
template<class T> using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;

template<typename... TArgs >
void INetInterface<TSubClass>::NetCall(void(TSubClass::*_pFunc)(CNetPeer*, TArgs...),
                                       CNetPeer* _pPeer, identity_t<TArgs>... params);
```

As a side note, `_Params` is a reserved identifier, along with `_ObjectData` and `_ObjectID`; you should rename them.

Comment: Thanks for the nice hints, I will try it out later. Seems like I have to change my coding style as I am using "_" for parameters. I have not thought about that I can collide with reserved identifiers this way.

Comment: I still dont understand why this is a conflict? The compiler could find the non error solution without violating type safety due to the function pointer being resolved first and "fixing" the possible TArgs parameter to one solution. Now when it sees the second use of TArgs it should continue using const CMessage& for it from the function signature first deduced. Applying that would not result in error. So is this not working by definition?

Comment: @ecreif Because the rule is that when it's used several times, then it's deduced independently and all deductions must match. Presumably one motivation for the rule is to avoid introducing unexpected conversions in ambiguous cases.